# wallet location from environment variable instead of sqlnet.ora for oci client

Tags: oracle, ssl, jdbc, ssl-certificate, oracle-call-interface

I have a oracle 11g database server and I am connecting to it from OCI client. This is working fine, but now the requirement is we need to connect to an SSL enabled database.

For that I had to create a sqlnet.ora and place it in the directory as specified in the TNS_ADMIN env. variable. In the sqlnet.ora I had to specify the wallet location. Also created certificates and put it in the wallet.

The above is working fine for me. But due to certain restrictions, we cannot create this sqlnet.ora in the client side. Is there a way we can pass this wallet location through some environment variables so that sqlnet.ora is not required?

If we create a jdbc connection, we can specify the wallet location through jdbc connection properties. Is there any such equivalent for OCI based connection. I dont mind how we make the wallet location available to OCI client, so long as I dont have to create a sqlnet.ora.

Any pointers is greatly appreciated

Comment: As I'm just in a comparable situation: Did you find a solution? In my case, it would be fine if I could use an environment variable in `sqlnet.ora` to specify the wallet location.

Comment: I got the same challenge: Use the system tns_admin settings but log in via a specified wallet instead of user/password.
Seems like modifying `sqlnet.ora` is actually the official solution, documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-oci-wallet.html#GUID-9DF57469-0823-4954-BAE8-2B09D61504E0

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the sqlnet.ora file. As an option, there is a solution like @Izzy was looking for. You can use an environment variable in the "directory" definition portion of the full wallet location:

```
WALLET_LOCATION = ..... (DIRECTORY=/home/$USER/oracle_wallet) ....
```

And unfortunately not what you're looking for, this is defined in a sqlnet.ora file.